# Cancel closing QWidget after clicking close button

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qevent

Is it possible to keep a `QWidget` open after close button clicked? Suppose that widget is main widget. i.e. not child of another widget.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would try to:

```
void Widget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    [..]
    event->ignore();
}
```

As documentation say:

> "For example, you can prevent the window from closing by calling
>   ignore() on all events."